# SQL count occurrences of a value

Tags: sql, wordpress, count

I am trying to count the occurrences of a value in SQL

```
id   |   my_id   |   field_number   |   field_id   |   value
------------------------------------------------------------
1    |    101    |       78         |     88       |   apple
2    |    287    |       76         |     55       |   orange
3    |    893    |       45         |     33       |   orange
4    |    922    |       23         |     33       |   grape
5    |    198    |       09         |     88       |   raisin
6    |    082    |       55         |     88       |   apple
```

If I use the following then it correctly tells me that there are 3 field_id's with the value of 88.....

```
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_db1 WHERE field_id=88");
```

But if I try and do this:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_db1 WHERE value=apple");
```

Then it does not work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the quotes around `apple`:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM wp_db1 WHERE value="apple"');
```